# JPanel size issue

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have Added two JPanels into a `JPanel` with `GridBagLayout`. Now the issue is :

When the main panel loads it shows the upper panel bit above the actual place it should be and when data from db loads into the `JTextfields` and `JComboBox` then panel goes to its actual size.

sample code:

```
public class JPanelIssue extends JPanel {
    public JPanelIssue() {
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.add(panel1, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.6, GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
    mainPanel.add(panel2, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER, 1.0, 0.4,GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));

    add(mainPanel, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
    }
}
```

`panel1` contains fields related to search criteria and `panel2` contains `JTable` dispalying reults.

Is there any problem of AWT event queue or any other problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds perfectly normal to me.  Got a screen shot or bet yet some sample code?

Comment: A bit more detail please. What state are the panels and fields being populated? Shown? Hidden? Are the sizes set? Does the user have to click something before these fields are populated?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have put sample code.

Comment: @Skepi I have given some details as well.

Comment: @eatSleepCode Showing some very small amount of code that will not display precisely your issue is not of much help for us. Consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) instead.

Answer (score 2):

comment only

not reproducible from this code snipped, because you forgot to add something about `JTextfields and JComboBox then panel goes to its actual size.`

> When the main panel loads it shows the upper panel bit above the
>   actual place it should be and when data from db loads into the
>   JTextfields and JComboBox then panel goes to its actual size.

`GBC` is based on `PreferredSize` came from `JComponents` back to the contianer (by assuming that about `JPanel`)

there are two ways

1. `(proper)`set proper PreferredSize for [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#JTextField%28int%29) and [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setPrototypeDisplayValue%28E%29) too
2. `(sizing hack)`override `getPreferredSize` for `JPanel` contains  `JTextField` and `JComboBox`
3. then all another parent(s) / containers should be notified without override any `setSize`, `setBounds`, `setPreferredSize`, only by `JFrame.pack()`

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I am not getting 3rd point and what to write in the overriden getPreferredSize method.